# Possible to Stream wav File to Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition?

Tags: .net, speech-recognition, uwp

Is there an out-of-the-box solution to stream a wav file/memory to a UWP app? Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition looks like it only accepts microphone input. Is there a way to use System.Speech.Recognition in a UWP app? Is there an official way to use Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition in a Windows desktop app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [Speech APIs](https://www.projectoxford.ai/speech), this is a set of REST API provided by Microsoft which can accept wav files.

Comment: Had I stayed longer at the BeMyApp hackathon, I would have learned this directly from you, and weeks earlier. Silly me for leaving early.

Comment: My hoped for answer was a way to perform speech recognition on the local desktop, not over a wire. Perhaps a future version of Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition will do so.

Comment: :) Yes ! At the moment only microphone with UWP but this is absolutely a needed feature to accept wav files too. See you on another hackathon.

Comment: I'm the OP. I've posted my project, which demonstrates how to use System.Speech and Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition, STT services from Bing, Google and Houndify at https://github.com/BSalita/Woundify/

Answer (score 0):

You can use VB-Audio Virtual cable http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm in order to transcribe a .wav file.

You can use Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition API in a console or desktop app in the same way you can reference the other UWP API:

- Edit "yourproject".csproj
- Add TargetPlatformVersion10.0 /TargetPlatformVersion below TargetFrameworkVersion
- Reload Project
- Add Reference->Browse Windows.winmd from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata
- Add Reference->Browse System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll.
- set "Copy Local=False" into System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime properties