# UWP Speech Recognition from File or Stream

Tags: c#, uwp, speech-recognition, speech

I have created a UWP Application that is capable of performing speech to text on audio received from a microphone. But, my goal is to do speech recognition from a file or a stream. From what I can see pouring over the documentation, those methods are not available for the UWP library. I easily found it searching through the .NET library [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtowavefile?view=netframework-4.7.2), but would prefer to stick with UWP if it is possible.

So, has anyone done speech to text from a file or stream using UWP?

Comment: Not sure if it can be done directly from the UWP app process, but you can leverage the .NET Framework API you linked in your question from your UWP by calling it from a desktop extension component which can perform the operation and then report the result back to your UWP app process. Here is a tutorial on how to use desktop extensions in UWP apps to leverage APIs and capabilities that are not available in UWP directly: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/

Comment: This [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301189/possible-to-stream-wav-file-to-windows-media-speechrecognition/34307409#34307409) might be helpful if you consider using online Azure API.

Answer (score 0):

The UWP Platform has both speech to text and text to speech capabilities built it.  Take a look at the samples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis) and the classes in the [SpeechRecognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition) namespace.

Comment: While I appreciate the response, I get the impression that you did not read the question. I also have a UWP application working with STT directly from a microphone and TTS from a string. But, I am trying to do both operations from/to a file.

Answer (score 0):

sorry i hope i understant your question (my english is poor)

but for now, only microphone with UWP, the only solution i see is to use (test) [woundify](https://github.com/BSalita/Woundify/)

i dont see that but its the same answer than @kennyzx